# How to rotate bitmap without changing file size?

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

I try do this:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/"+ photoName + ".jpg");

        int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
        int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        matrix.postRotate(90);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width,
                height, matrix, true);

        FileOutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                "/sdcard/" + photoName + "-rotate.jpg",
                    System.currentTimeMillis()));

        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
```

rotated file size > original file size, because rotated file resolution = 96 dpi, but original file = 72 dpi. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add in the following line right before `FileOutputStream os;`:

```
resizedBitmap.setDensity(bitmapOrig.getDensity());
```

Comment: @sherman this only affects the pixel density, not the file size. From the documentation: "it is possible that the returned bitmap from BitmapFactory could be in a different bitdepth, and/or may have lost per-pixel alpha (e.g. JPEG only supports opaque pixels)." Additionally, you are specifying quality of `100`, which could result in a larger output than input.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that another possible solution is to change the first line:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/"+ photoName + ".jpg");
```

With the code:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/"+ photoName + ".jpg", (new BitmapFactory.Options()).inDensity=0);
```

But I did not check this solution.

Moreover, it seems to me that your solution should also work. I think there is somewhere an error in the AOSP, because:

1. Function `createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)` does not change the density of the file (`bitmap.mDensity = source.mDensity;`) . New density is equal to density of the source. Thus, it seems that the density is changed before this call.
2. `BitmapFactory.decodeFile calls BitmapFactory.decodeFile` with the parameters `(pathName, null)`
3. `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, null)` transforms file into the stream and calls `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, opts)` where opts = null
4. `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, opts)` call native function `bm = nativeDecodeStream(is, tempStorage, outPadding, opts);` and then calls `finishDecode(bm, outPadding, opts);` Remember that in our case opts are equal to null.
5. In the `finishDecode(bm, outPadding, opts)` there is the first check that should return bitmap unchanged (opts in our case should be null):

   if (bm == null || opts == null) {
               return bm;
   }
6. Thus, it seems that something bad has happened with opts in the native function: `nativeDecodeStream(is, tempStorage, outPadding, opts)`

It needs a lot of time to check further where the problem is. Also, I'm not sure that I'm right in my findings.